# Why "int" doesn't get inherited in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Number {
    int mark;
}

class One extends Number {
    mark = 1; //error: variable mark not initiated.
}
```

It's because I have to use it in a method:

```
int getMark( Number n) {
return n.Mark; 
//returns 1 if Object passed is of "One" class
}
```

So why is that error showing in line 5 of first code.

Edit: Typo, It's "Number" only.

Comment: The code above won't compile, but not for the reason you state. You can't have code just freestanding in the middle of a class, it needs to be in an initializer, constructor, or method. Also, `number` != `Number`, Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: Is `One` really defined inside `Number`?
Does it extend `number` or `Number`?

Answer (score 3):

Your initialization code in the subclass needs to occur inside a constructor, method, or initializer block. Something like this (using a constructor):

```
class One extends Number {
    public One() {
        mark = 1;
    }
}
```

or like this (using an initializer block):

```
class One extends Number {
    {
        mark = 1;
    }
}
```

See the Java tutorial topic [Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for more information. (By the way, `Number` is a terrible class name because it collides with a class name in `java.lang` that every Java program implicitly imports.)

It would be better, however, to put the initialization of `mark` in the code for `Number`, since it is good programming practice to keep the management of the field in the same class in which it is declared. This can be done by defining an appropriate constructor for `Number`:

```
class Number {
    int mark;

    /** Explicit initialization constructor */
    Number(int mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    /** Default constructor (perhaps not needed?) */
    Number() {
        // assign default value to mark (if 0 is not a good default)
    }
}

class One extends Number {
    One() {
        super(1); // calls the explicit initialization constructor
    }
}
```

Eventually, you should also give some thought to what access specifiers (`public`, `protected` or `private`) would be appropriate.

As far as referencing the variable in the method `getMark`, the problem there is that `mark` is not the same as `Mark`. Java is case sensitive when it comes to variable names. Rewrite the method to refer to the variable correctly:

```
int getMark( Number n) {
    return n.mark; 
    //returns 1 if Object passed is of "One" class
}
```

I would also suggest making `getMark()` a method of your `Number` class, rather than an external method. Then you could use `n.getMark()` instead of `getMark(n)` to get the current value of `mark`. You could then declare `mark` to be `private` (and perhaps `final` as well), since [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) and [immutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) are always good things in OOP.